# Uri.withAppendedPath method

Tags: android, sms, uri, contacts

I want to create an SMS Android app. I read the SMS sender's name and the body of the message, then I show them in a list view. I use the following URI for reading the sender's name from the sender's number.

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(senderNumber));
```

What does this line of code do?

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This filters the Contact from Phonebook based upon `senderNumber`

**Example**

```
/*
 * Returns contact's id
 */
private String getContactId(String phoneNumber, Context context) {
    ContentResolver mResolver = context.getContentResolver();

    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
            Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

    Cursor cursor = mResolver.query(uri, new String[] {
            PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup._ID }, null, null, null);

    String contactId = "";

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            contactId = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup._ID));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    cursor = null;
    return contactId;
}
```

In this example you will get data from two columns only  `PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME` and `PhoneLookup._ID` based on the query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need a bit more detail. what does it returns to me when I query this uri?

Comment: It returns you a Cursor that points to the result in database. You can iterate the data through that cursor.

Comment: I think this uri points to a single contact but we use columns when we want to get name. I mean we interact with it like a table and it is ambiguous for me. By the way I am very new to android and content provider.

Comment: The cursor points to the resulting table and you can access multiple rows through it like I showed you in example using While loop. Like when you execute a query to database and it returns you only the columns you specify in query similarly cursor points to the rows of the resulting table.